# dacpac SQL database deploy task devops not updating tables

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I have a basic SQL Server database set to 2019 version. I have a task that is reporting all green

Steps:

```
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Deploy someDb_DB'
  inputs:
    DacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dbproj/dbproj/db.dacpac'
    ServerName: '(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB'
    DatabaseName: db
```

I  have set my authentication as SQL Authentication. I am deploying to my local machine via deployment group and the Azagent.

The task above is reporting all good. However I do not have SOMETABLE in the database. Yes I have refreshed, disconnected, reconnected etc.. Its just not there.

```
2024-01-23T23:25:42.4291157Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy db
2024-01-23T23:25:42.4690830Z ==============================================================================
2024-01-23T23:25:42.4690949Z Task         : SQL Server database deploy
2024-01-23T23:25:42.4690985Z Description  : Deploy a SQL Server database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
2024-01-23T23:25:42.4691037Z Version      : 0.198.0
2024-01-23T23:25:42.4691065Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-01-23T23:25:42.4691100Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group
2024-01-23T23:25:42.4691168Z ==============================================================================
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7586121Z Publishing to database 'db' on server '(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB'. 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7586417Z Initializing deployment (Start) 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7586533Z Initializing deployment (Complete) 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7586649Z Analyzing deployment plan (Start) 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7586759Z Analyzing deployment plan (Complete) 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7587656Z Updating database (Start) 

2024-01-23T23:25:58.7587785Z Creating Table [dbo].[SOMETABLE]... <<<<<<THIS IS THE TABLE GETTING CREATED

2024-01-23T23:25:58.7587908Z Update complete. 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7588003Z Updating database (Complete) 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7588100Z Successfully published database. 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7588445Z Changes to connection setting default values were incorporated in a recent release.  More information is available at https://aka.ms/dacfx-connection 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7588683Z Time elapsed 0:00:13.56 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.7588757Z 
2024-01-23T23:25:58.8091739Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy db
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong. I know dacpac requires a sysadmin acct.. and I would assume if something went wrong, I would get an error.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue from my side. Comparing my log with yours, it looks like the deployment was successful and the table was successfully created. To narrow down the issue, you can try these: 1. Deploy your DB using MS-hosted agent or a self-hosted agent instead of using deployment group. Check what's the result. 2. [Use Sqlpackage.exe to publish your DACPAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver16) on your local machine and check if it works.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT this task already uses sqlPackage.exe to my knowledge. I hit a wall at first with an error saying unable to locate sqlPacakge.exe. I downloaded and installed locally the DacFramework.msi. This resolved the complaint that sqlPackage.exe could not be found.  I followed this to install the sqlpackage:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488685/azure-devops-unable-to-find-the-location-of-dac-framework-sqlpackage-exe-from

Comment: " this task already uses sqlPackage.exe" - Yes, you are right. The reason I suggest you use Sqlpackage.exe to publish your DACPAC on your local machine is to check whether this issue is related to the pipeline. If running the same command locally gets the same result, then this issue isn't related to the pipeline. As I said, I have tested from my side using the same task and configuration, all work as expected. Based on the current situation, it's suggested to create a brand new local server and try the same deployment to check if it has the same issue or not.

Comment: To create a new local server, you can run `sqllocaldb create LocalDBName` to create and run `sqllocaldb start LocalDBName` to start it. Besides, you can double check if you check SOMETABLE in the correct folder and correct DB.